# TFS Service 2012 Build Process Template (XAML Workflow) with FTP Publishing (Deployment)

Tags: tfs, ftp, tfsbuild, web-deployment, azure-devops

I have web site project hosted at [TFS Cloud](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). And I have hosting account at Godaddy, which allows me to deploy sites via FTP only.
I create publishing profile in Visual Studio 2012 and can successfully execute publishing to FTP in  Visual Studio.

**The problem**:
This the task cannot be done using any standard TFS Build template and neither its standard workflow activities, even though it should be a trivial thing people do with TFS Build server. There is no ready "copy-paste" solution (wpp.targets) on MSBuild for that: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FTP.targets"
Clearly says that it is not supported through the command line, one should use VS for that.

**Question**:
Is there any implemented solutions of that task that I can just copy paste to my team project with few clicks?

I expected to see lots of articles about it in web, however I didn't find any simple existing solution. Articles like [this](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/09/21/continuous-integration-tip-1-ndash-ftp-deployment) require me to install some 3rd party software (which is not an option in most popular hosting like Godaddy), and it's not clear how to use it with TFS.

Answer (score 0):

In the default Build template, go to the process section and choose Msbuild Arguments and give the publishing profile.

MSBuild Arguments    :   /p:DebugSymbols=false;DebugType=None;DeployOnBuild=true;**PublishProfile=YourProfileName**

when Build got succeeded, it will be deployed to the ftp location.

this link may help you more : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx